Where to locate a custom modal tailwind class scaffolded by Laravel Jetstream
Below is part of the modal component generated when on installs Jetstream in laravel with livewire project. The parent div has a jetstream-modal class which to my understanding is not a built-in tailwind class. Where can I locate this class styles?
<div x-data="{ show: @entangle($attributes->wire('model')) }" x-on:close.stop="show = false" x-on:keydown.escape.window="show = false" x-show="show"
    id="{{ $id }}" class="fixed inset-0 z-50 px-4 py-6 overflow-y-auto jetstream-modal sm:px-0"
    style="display: none;">
    <div x-show="show" class="fixed inset-0 transition-all transform" x-on:click="show = false"
        x-transition:enter="ease-out duration-300" x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0"
        x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100" x-transition:leave="ease-in duration-200"
        x-transition:leave-start="opacity-100" x-transition:leave-end="opacity-0">
        <div class="absolute inset-0 bg-gray-500 opacity-75"></div>
    </div>

    <div x-show="show"
        class="mb-6 bg-white rounded-lg overflow-hidden shadow-xl transform transition-all sm:w-full {{ $maxWidth }} sm:mx-auto"
        x-trap.inert.noscroll="show" x-transition:enter="ease-out duration-300"
        x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0 translate-y-4 sm:translate-y-0 sm:scale-95"
        x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100 translate-y-0 sm:scale-100" x-transition:leave="ease-in duration-200"
        x-transition:leave-start="opacity-100 translate-y-0 sm:scale-100"
        x-transition:leave-end="opacity-0 translate-y-4 sm:translate-y-0 sm:scale-95">
        {{ $slot }}
    </div>
</div>

